# Testing firestore with disableNetwork

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, offline

I have a question about possibly testing a web application using Firebase Firestore. I understand that I can `enablePersistence` and `disableNetwork`, which will result in reading from / writing to offline cache. I could potentially use this for my tests.

However, after the test has been completed, is it possible to clear the changes in cache before I `enableNetwork` again?